# Unable to uninstall Folder Lock or access locked drive

Tags: windows, folder-lock

I locked my D drive using folder lock. But, my D drive contained the installed files of folder lock too. Now I am not able to run folder lock nor open D drive.

I tried uninstalling from Control Panel but it said "Access denied".

Comment: Have you tried to reboot? Besides that end the process and start the program from another disk and try to unlock the folder that way.  I would guess this program doesn't actually place anything in the register so it can be extracted to a folder and the program can be ran from any directory.

Comment: Is this the computer equivalent of locking your keys in the car?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. I'm not sure about it.

1. Before the "WINDOWS" screen at starting press <kbd>F8</kbd> to enter the screen to safe mode.
   run your computer in safe mode and then start folder lock it will run and don't ask for password and then unlock your files hope this help.
2. otherwise just Enter your reg. key as password and you will successively access the folder lock.
3. Otherwise run registry by typing `regedit' after clicking Start button in Windows and then click Run. Then delete this string value:

   > HKEY_CURRENT_USER > Software > FolderLock6 > LastLockerPath

Once you are done, try uninstalling from Start menu > Programs > Folder Lock
and then select uninstall.

After uninstalling Folder Lock 6 please go to My Documents and search for a file name locker with extension (`*FLK`) or (`*FLKW`) and delete. Do not forget to restart you computer before trying to delete or to open you locked files.

Answer (score -1):

I was in the same situation

Just go ahead and install a new/fresh copy of folder lock with a same pwd and version  on a different drive

This resolved my issue